# scanf is terminating before the termination condition

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements

**PROGRAM**: A survey to know the popularity of four cars (Ambassador, Fiat, Dolphin and Maruti) was conducted in four cities (Bombay, Calcutta, Delhi and Madras). Each person surveyed was asked to give his city and the type of car he was using. The results, in coded form, are tabulated as follows:

```
M 1 C 2 B 1 D 3 M 2 B 4
C 1 D 3 M 4 B 2 D 1 C 3
D 4 D 4 M 1 M 1 B 3 B 3
C 1 C 1 C 2 M 4 M 4 C 2
D 1 C 2 B 3 M 1 B 1 C 2
D 3 M 4 C 1 D 2 M 3 B 4
```

Codes represent the following information:

M - Madras 1 - Ambassador

D – Delhi 2 - Fiat

C – Calcutta 3 - Dolphin

B – Bombay 4 - Maruti

Write a program to produce a table showing the popularity of various cars in four cities.

**PROBLEM:** The `scanf` in the `for` loop isn't taking input as per the condition I've mentioned. The loop is supposed to run 36 times so that I can input data 36 times, rather it takes only 19 inputs and then the loop ends. I don't know why it's happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    unsigned short car, i, survey[5][5] = {{0},{0},{0},{0},{0}};
    char city;
    printf("Enter city initial and car code\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c %hu",&city,&car);
        switch (city)
        {
        case 'b':
            survey[1][car]++;
            break;
        case 'c':
            survey[2][car]++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            survey[3][car]++;
            break;
        default:
            survey[4][car]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("BOMBAY:\nAmbassador = %hu\nFiat = %hu\nDolphin = %hu\nMaruti = %hu\n",survey[1][1],survey[1][2],survey[1][3],survey[1][4]);
    printf("CALCUTTA:\nAmbassador = %hu\nFiat = %hu\nDolphin = %hu\nMaruti = %hu\n",survey[2][1],survey[2][2],survey[2][3],survey[2][4]);
    printf("DELHI:\nAmbassador = %hu\nFiat = %hu\nDolphin = %hu\nMaruti = %hu\n",survey[3][1],survey[3][2],survey[3][3],survey[3][4]);
    printf("MADRAS:\nAmbassador = %hu\nFiat = %hu\nDolphin = %hu\nMaruti = %hu\n",survey[4][1],survey[4][2],survey[4][3],survey[4][1]);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
m 1
c 2
b 1
d 3
m 2
b 4
c 1
d 3
m 4
b 2
d 1
c 3
d 4
d 4
m 1
m 1
b 3
b 3
c 1
BOMBAY:
Ambassador = 1
Fiat = 1
Dolphin = 2
Maruti = 1
CALCUTTA:
Ambassador = 1
Fiat = 1
Dolphin = 1
Maruti = 0
DELHI:
Ambassador = 1
Fiat = 0
Dolphin = 2
Maruti = 2
MADRAS:
Ambassador = 9
Fiat = 4
Dolphin = 5
Maruti = 9
```

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%c %hu", ...)` try `scanf(" %c %hu", ...)` (note the leading space).

Comment: Also, remember that array-indexes are zero-based. If you write your programs to have one-based indexes you will be pretty much alone.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude still doesn't solve the problem. I tried to insert the printf part before the scanf, but it's behaving weird in the output.

Comment: The space is definitely needed, otherwise the second call to `scanf` will set the `city` to the newline left over from the first call. Once that happens, all input will be out of sync and all remaining calls will fail. And you *always* need to check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Upper-case versus lower-case? The character `'C'` is *not* the same as the character `'c'`!

Comment: And add a specific case for `'m'`, and use the `default` case for handling invalid input.

Comment: After adding some extra checks and outputs (like a proper case for `'m'`), [my own example](https://godbolt.org/z/caMq61vx7) shows all problems: The leading space in the format string, the failing of `scanf` (when it returns `1`), and the lower-/upper-case problem. To summarize: Leading space in the format string; Checking the result of `scanf`; And handle both upper- and lower-case input. [Here's an example I wrote](https://godbolt.org/z/nxczxnY1T), with all fixes, and error handling, and more improvements.